# Bounds on the distance moved after $t$ steps of gradient descent on a Lipschitz continous function

Tags: optimization, solution-verification, lipschitz-functions, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I am looking to provide a theoretical bound on the distance moved by gradient descent of fixed steps $t$ on a Lipschitz continous function, for the purpose of providing some theoretical backing for an empirical algorithm. I don't have much experiences with proofs so I'm looking for some advice on whether my proof is rigorous and error free.

Given a $K$-Lipschitz function, by definition:
$$
|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \leq K|x_1 - x_2|
$$
Let $x_1 = x_2 + \delta x$, and taking limits:
$$
\lim_{\delta x\to 0}\bigg|\frac{f(x_2+\delta x) - f(x_2)}{\delta x}\bigg| \leq K
$$
$$
|\nabla f| \leq K
$$

For gradient descent, the update formula is:
$$
x_{t+1} = x_t - \eta \nabla f(x_t)
$$
Therefore, the squared distance moved in the first step of gradient descent is bounded:
$$
\|x_1 - x_0\|^2 =  (\eta \|\nabla f(x_0)\|)^2 \\
$$
$$
\|x_1 - x_0\|^2 \leq \eta^2 K^2
$$
We can therefore conclude that the distance moved in $t$ steps of gradient descent where $t \geq 1$ on a $K$-Lipschitz function is bounded by:
$$
\|x_{t} - x_0\|^2 \leq \eta^2 K^2 t
$$

Is there anything that I'm doing incorrectly or missing. Thanks in advance!